# New-AzureRmADApplication throwing exception of type System.Exception

Tags: asp.net, powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create Azure AD application using below command but it is throwing exception of type System.Exception

> New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName SampleADApp -HomePage
>   "http://SampleApplication" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplication"

I am using Azure Powershell version 3.0 and AzureRM 4.3.1

If I create AAD Application from azure portal then it works fine but again giving same error if I try to create :

> New-AzureRMADServicePrincipal

Comment: Can you execute your script with $DebugPreference="Continue" to produce additional debugging information and include it here?

Comment: Thanks for amazing idea. DebugPreference solve all my problems. I would like mark your comment as accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, @arpan desai , I'm glad to hear that my comment can help you. I will write it as an answer,then you can mark it to help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  execute your script with `$DebugPreference="Continue"`to produce additional debugging information . Then you can get the Error value details  and you can resolve this issue through it.

Answer (score 0):

The first one might be because IdentifierUris is an array. Try specifying it as:

```
New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName SampleADApp -HomePage "http://SampleApplication" -IdentifierUris @("http://NewApplication")
```